# Solar panel and Equinox

Tags: time, astronomy, sun

At Equinox the number of hours of daylight and night is equal so 12 hours of each...

is this from 6am to 6pm? how can we know which hours this daylight happens for.

The question is:

Over which hours of the day can this home in San Diego acquire energy from the sun
(assuming cloudless conditions on the Equinox).

i am assuming 6am to 6pm but i feel like thats wrong because noon the maximum position of sun does not always happen at 12

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/equinox-not-equal.html

Comment: There are tables of sunrise and sunset times for every day of the year for various cities. For example: https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/usa/san-diego?month=3&year=2020

Comment: Once upon a time, If you or the town you lived in were wealthy enough to own a clock, you would set it to local, astronomical noon as indicated by the sun dial in your garden. That practice was brought to an end by the invention of [railroad schedules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Railway_time) and the need to synchronize the clocks in geographically separate places. Now we have "time zones," and those somewhat decouple the time shown on your wrist watch or cell phone from the exact position of the Sun in the sky above your neighborhood.

Comment: Atmospheric refraction and sun finite angular size work as such that is not true that at equinox the durations of light and dark - as sensed by us - equal each others.